# How to zoom out of only the terminal in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, zooming

Opened a new project in vs code and the terminal was zoomed in too much but everything else was at a normal zoom level. Not sure how to only zoom out of only the terminal in vs code

I tried clicking view > appearance > zoom out but the whole vs code window zoomed out instead of just the terminal

Comment: You have to click on the terminal tab and then click view > appearance > zoom out

Answer (score 5):

You can change the font size of the terminal. Go to Preferences and search for *Terminal font size*. Under Features -> Terminal, you'll find the *Terminal - Integrated: Font Size* option. You can adjust its value based on your requirements to change the font size of the terminal.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check if [VSCode 1.86 (Jan. 2024)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_86.md#zoom-terminal-via-mouse-wheel) would help:

> ### Zoom terminal via mouse wheel
>
> The terminal can now be zoomed in and out with the mouse wheel when enabled with this setting:
>
> ```
> "terminal.integrated.mouseWheelZoom": true
> ```

It comes from [issue 76381](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/76381), and [PR 200639](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/200639), and is available in [VSCode Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/).
It seems easier than the ["Terminal Zoom" extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=trybick.terminal-zoom).

Answer (score 1):

And if you want a bindable command to zoom only the terminal in or out, that is coming in v1.87, see [Add commands to zoom in/out/reset for terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/453f8fba116357e5fd4a9cb3f9c81ac7b2f63986).

They will be:

```
workbench.action.terminal.fontZoomIn
"Terminal: Increase Font Size"          

workbench.action.terminal.fontZoomOut
"Terminal: Decrease Font Size"

workbench.action.terminal.fontZoomReset
"Terminal: Reset Font Size"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can adjust terminal font size by typing "terminal font size" after clicking the settings icon in vs code
2. You can also delete this line "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 60 from the settings.json file that might be in your .vscode folder. This was the solution to my problem
   [image]